# java8 + mariadb 5.6: How to get autogenerated value when insert a blob

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have a mariadb table with 2 cols: rowid int pk autogenerated and imagen blob.

By using "CallableStatement sentence = mariaConn.prepareCall(myinsert);" I'm able to add a new row with a blob into "imagen" BUT I can't get the autogenerated pk col "rowid".

By the other hand, using "Statement sentence = mariaConn.prepareStatement(myinsert);" I can get the autogenerated col "rowid" but I can't add a blob into "imagen" (only do if it is empty).

Is there a way to do both things at one call? (trying to avoid a Statement insert to get the pk and then a CallableStatement to update the blob).

Note: in Oracle is pretty simple using CallableStatement because Oracle's insert has a "returning" clause <= I'm trying to emulate it on mariadb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need CallableStatement to insert blob, a simple prepared statement

```
insert into table(imagen) values(?)
```

works,and with that you can get autogenerated value if you use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS during preparation, and Statement.getGeneratedKeys() after execution. You also can do

```
select last_insert_id()
```

any time, but this is less efficient.

There is no MariaDB 5.6 btw.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav for your quick response. Even so I have a doubt: How you replace "?" in a Statement which it has not such method as CallableStatement.setBlob? ... and I cannot do such thing as "insert into myTable values (myBlob)" in a single Statement (it is not a String) ... Or I am wrong?  Thanks in advance. Nestor.

Comment: And as @Vladislav says it is not mariadb 5.6 but =>  MariaDB [mysql]>  select @@version;  
+----------------+  
| @@version |  
+----------------+  
| 5.5.56-MariaDB |  
+----------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)  

MariaDB [mysql]>   I apologize about the confusion.  Nestor

Comment: there is PreparedStatement.setBlob(), however due to implementation, it is better to use PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream() in mariadb, if you can do this.

Comment: Thanks @Vladislav, you rocks !!! PreparedStatement is what I was looking for. It has methods to get autoGeneratedKeys and to set values before execute.  Thanks a lot for your time and knowledge.  Nestor.